# Return from a loop from a different method

Tags: ruby

My understanding is you can exit from a program with a return. How do you return from a loop? When I run `return_method` as in the following, I want to exit the loop with `"RETURNING"` returned.

```
def return_method
   return "RETURNING"
end

loop do
  puts "Enter:"
  answer = gets.chomp
  if answer == 'run'
    return_method
  end
  break if answer == 'y'
end
```

`break` doesn't work within my method.

Comment: `return return_method`? Or do you want to print something?

Comment: I want to return return_method

Answer (score 1):

A typical way to escape from nested loops of from nested method calls is to use `catch` ... `throw`.

```
RETURNING = "RETURNING"

def return_method
  throw RETURNING
end

catch(RETURNING) do
  loop do
    puts "Enter:"
    answer = gets.chomp
    if answer == 'run'
      return_method
    end
    break if answer == 'y'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not the case that a method call forces the calling method to do something as abrupt as `return`. That's what exceptions are for, they will bubble up if not caught, but that's seriously heavy-handed for this sort of thing. Instead make your method return a truthy value if you want to break the loop:

```
def return_method
   puts "RETURNING"

   true
end

loop do
  puts "Enter:"
  answer = gets.chomp

  case (answer)
  when 'run'
    break if return_method
  when 'y'
    break
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm trying to get a better handle on how returns work in Ruby and I can't find anything online on how they work. Would you happen to know of any resources I could take a look at? Thanks again.

Comment: `return` simply returns from a method or block. It's only special inside a `do ... end` type structure such as in `x.each do ... end`. A method call has no special rules, but blocks come in two types, one that allows a `return` and one that disallows. This is the difference between `lambda` and `Proc.new`. A `return` inside something declared with `Proc.new` *will* force-exit, but not in a `lambda`.